# iOS UIImagePickerController showed blank page

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I tried to present and dismiss the UIImagePickerController continuity

**Here is my code**

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

func showImagePickerController() {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(self.imagePicker, animated: true)
}

// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage.rawValue] as? UIImage {
        imageViewGroup.image = image
        isChoosePhoto = true
    }
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

**Here is the result:**

[image: plant page]

**Here is the error log:**

> UIImagePickerController UIViewController create error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker.viewservice was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker.viewservice was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid.}

So, what should I do to fix this issue

Comment: share some code first

Comment: Hi @AjharulIslam, I've just updated my question.

Comment: Are you using any service extension?

Comment: Hi @Shruti I do not use any extension.

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift 4 there are two pre-requisite for the `UIImagePicker`. Check if you have done that

1) The delegate for the UIImagePickerController is `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate` so need to explicitly add the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` as one of the protocols:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
UINavigationControllerDelegate { .... }
```

2) Make sure that the `info.plist` has the `Privacy - Photo library Usage Description` key and String value set.