# image picker/UIImagePickerController show blank screen/NavigationController swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to get answer from this question answer link but failed :(

[iOS UIImagePickerController showed blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52403232/5509769)

Then I try below code but still show blank screen without image list :(
I think don't fire the delegation function
You can also check from GitHub

https://github.com/MdAshfaqurRahmanIOS/image-picker-3

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        present(imagePicker, animated: true)
    }
}
extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage")] as? UIImage {
            imageView.image = image
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

> **Add this info.plist**
> key =>>>> Privacy - Photo Library Usage
> value =>> please access photogallery

**Console log**

- 2020-12-17 22:49:11.928762+0600 image-picker-3[1309:51223]
  [lifecycle] [u B37332A2-92E0-4D65-981B-0DBBDB4534D9:m (null)]
  [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker(1.0)] Connection to plugin
  interrupted while in use. 2020-12-17 22:49:11.944027+0600
  image-picker-3[1309:51223] [lifecycle] [u
  B37332A2-92E0-4D65-981B-0DBBDB4534D9:m (null)]
  [com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker(1.0)] Connection to plugin
  invalidated while in use. 2020-12-17 22:49:12.003410+0600
  image-picker-3[1309:51015] UIImagePickerController UIViewController
  create error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The
  connection to service on pid 0 named
  com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker.viewservice was interrupted,
  but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this
  proxy has become invalid." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The
  connection to service on pid 0 named
  com.apple.mobileslideshow.photo-picker.viewservice was interrupted,
  but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this
  proxy has become invalid.}

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow my programmatically example below, first add your button and delegates to your controller and import Photo framework:

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class YourViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

lazy var takePicButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setTitle("Present img picker", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlepickPicture), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return button
}()
```

now in viewDidLoad add button and set constraints:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(takePicButton)
    takePicButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    takePicButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    takePicButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    takePicButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

After that set your func to present image picker controller:

```
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

@objc fileprivate func handlepickPicture() {
    
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.view.tintColor = .white
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
    
    checkPermission()
}
```

check the permission, don't forget to set your info.plist privacy usage description (like you):

```
fileprivate func checkPermission() {
    let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
        print("Add Photo")
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            print("Access is granted by user")
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        print("Access is granted by user")
    case .notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
            (newStatus) in
            print("status is \(newStatus)")
            if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                /* do stuff here */
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                print("success")
            }
        })
        print("It is not determined until now")
    case .restricted:
        // same same
        print("User do not have access to photo album.")
        goToSetting()
    case .denied:
        // same same
        print("Text tapped...")
        goToSetting()
        print("User has denied the permission.")
    case .limited:
        goToSetting() // the function show an alert to enable Authorization manually
        print("User has denied the permission.")
    @unknown default:
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

write the function to set authorization manually:

```
fileprivate func goToSetting() {
    let title = "Oooooops!"
    let message = "Hi man, for use this App press Go To settings and enabled access to Pohto Gallery... Check read and write option and relaunch the App!"
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let subview = (alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.first!)! as UIView
    subview.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.2)
    
    alertController.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .heavy),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]), forKey: "attributedTitle")
    alertController.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: message, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]), forKey: "attributedMessage")
    
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) { (_) in
        print("Action cancelled")
    }
    
    let goToSettingPermission = UIAlertAction(title: "Go To setting", style: .default) { (action) in
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    alertController.addAction(goToSettingPermission)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
    })
}
```

this is the result, on dx the alert for manual authorization, on left the picker controller

[image]

If you don't see the preview photos, try to run app with another simulator device.

Comment: I use it with UIImagePickerController. Have you any idea where is my mistake @Fabio

Comment: @Ashfaqur_Rahman run your (not mine but your original) code with another simulator device, if the result is the same, I think the error in your code is that you have not implemented authorization request case (checkPermission() function)  .... With these few elements available it is the only thing that comes in my mind ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use it by taking these photos into a collectionView like this "I've made it using RxSwift:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import Foundation
import Photos

private let reuseIdentifier = "ImageCell"

class ImagesCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
//MARK: - vars
private var images = [PHAsset]()
private var selectedPhotoSubject = PublishSubject<UIImage>()
var selectedPhoto: Observable<UIImage> {
    return selectedPhotoSubject.asObservable()
}

//MARK: - LifeCycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    linkPhotosLibrary()
    self.title = "Pick an Image"
    
}
//MARK: - PhotoLibrary
private func linkPhotosLibrary() {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { [weak self] status in
        if status == .authorized {
            
            let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image,options: nil)
            assets.enumerateObjects { (object, count, stop) in
                self?.images.append(object)
            }
            self?.images.reverse()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    
    let asset = images[indexPath.row]
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200,height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil) { image, _ in
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.imageViewOutlet.image = image
        }
    }
    
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let selectedAsset = images[indexPath.row]
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: selectedAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil) { [weak self] image , info in
        guard let info = info else {return}
        let isDegradedImage = info["PHImageResultIsDegradedKey"] as! Bool
        // as we will call this function 2 times one for the small image in the collection and one here that's why we use it as this will tell us if the image is thumbnail or original image
        if !isDegradedImage {
            
            if let image = image {
                self?.selectedPhotoSubject.onNext(image)
                self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

or you can use it normally:

```
    var myGallery: GalleryController!

    func showGalleryImages () {
        
        self.myGallery = GalleryController()
        self.myGallery.delegate = self
        Config.tabsToShow = [.imageTab, .cameraTab]
        Config.Camera.imageLimit = 100
        
        self.present(self.myGallery, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. you suggest me use a pod file with i.e. **Rxswift** that's working good but I need swift build in **UIImagePickerController** have you any idea where is my mistake @Menaim